# R logical indexing by equality on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe, `df`:

```
           A    B      C
     1     4   25      a
     2     3   79      b
     3     4   25      c
     4     6   17      d
     5     4   21      e
     6     5   25      f
```

How to I index the lines where elements in certain columns match a vector, e.g. `df$A == 4 & df$B == 25`?

I would have thought something like: `df[df[,c("A", "B")] == c(4, 25),]` would have worked, but this doesn't give me the right answer (it returns no lines).

I would like a method that uses a vector of column names to match on, and a vector of values to match.

Comment: Why not `mydf[mydf$A == 4 & mydf$B == 25,]`?

Comment: Because I would like the flexibility to dynamically specify the columns and values to match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[colSums(t(df[,c("A", "B")]) == c(4, 25))==2,]
  x A  B C
1 1 4 25 a
3 3 4 25 c
```

This works recycling the vector `c(4, 25)`.

Comment: Nice, thanks very much, could it perhaps be improved by using:
`df[apply(t(df[,c("A", "B")]) == c(4, 25), all, 2)` sp that you could have variable length columns? Either way, thanks so much

Comment: You mean like `df[apply(t(df[,c("A", "B")]) == c(4, 25), 2, function(x) sum(x) == 2),]`? If you consider this an improvement...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a simple `merge`, which would have analogies for `data.table` and `dplyr` and in `sql` as well:

```
merge(df, setNames(list(4,25),c("A","B")))
#  A  B C
#1 4 25 a
#2 4 25 c
```